# Configuring Apache with Trinidad and a Jruby on Rails app

Tags: jruby, jrubyonrails, trinidad-gem

The Trinidad docs tell how to get a Jruby on Rails app up and running in detail, but can someone tell me / point me to a good tutorial on how to configure Apache to use the Trinidad server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Trinidad wiki describes how to [configure AJP](https://github.com/trinidad/trinidad/wiki/AJP-Configuration) to connect Apache to Trinidad:

```
jruby -S trinidad --ajp 8099
```

Once Trinidad is configured to use AJP, you need to [configure Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy_ajp.html) to connect to AJP.  First enable the ajp module:

```
$ sudo a2enmod proxy_ajp
```

Then, configure Apache to connect to ajp on the port you defined on Trinidad in the `httpd.conf` file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ProxyPass / ajp://localhost:8099/
  ProxyPassReverse / ajp://localhost:8099/
</VirtualHost>
```

Check out the [Trinidad page](https://github.com/trinidad/trinidad/wiki/ajp-configuration#load_balancing) for more details on load balancing.

Finally, you should get [Deploying with JRuby](http://pragprog.com/book/jkdepj/deploying-with-jruby) if you want to go deeper into how to configure and deploy your JRuby apps on Trinidad using Capistrano/Puppet.  It's a very good book.

Comment: Awesome!! thank you so much you're a lifesaver, seriously. Also, if I wanted to serve static assets from apache all I would need is `ProxyPass /assets !`, am I correct? Also for anyone reading this who would like to do this for an https site, this really helped: http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2012/08/08/setting-up-apache-as-a-ssl-front-end-for-play/